# LDAP group membership filter used in RT3

Tags: perl, ldap, rt

I am trying to setup LDAP authentication to an Active Directory server for an [RT3](http://bestpractical.com/rt/) site.

I think that there is an error in the LDAP authentication module, but I really do not understand what the filter is trying to do. See [`RT/Authen/ExternalAuth/LDAP.pm` line 126](https://metacpan.org/source/FALCONE/RT-Authen-ExternalAuth-0.11/lib/RT/Authen/ExternalAuth/LDAP.pm#L126):

```
$ldap_msg = $ldap->search(  base   => $group,
                            filter => $filter,
                            attrs  => \@attrs,
                            scope  => 'base');
```

There is a config file that specifies the `group`, `group_attr` and `group_attr_value`.

Group is passed as `$group`, and the filter is created from a `group_attr=group` string. In my case `group_attr = present` and the `memberOf` line comes back with `CN=ITAdmins,CN=Builtin,DC=SPGLOBAL,DC=local` and the filter becomes `Filter: (present=CN=ITAdmins,CN=Builtin,DC=SPGLOBAL,DC=local)` and `Attrs: dn`.

This is invalid for a filter, but can any one who knows a bit more about this see what is meant to be happening?

Comment: There's an RT mailing list. Folks from best practical read it. You try asking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the link to the code, that makes it much simpler to understand.

So the model is, authentitcate with username and password, then $group, if defined means check that they are a member of a group to let them in.

$group should be a full LDAP DN, so cn=AccessGroup,ou=Groups,dc=myDomain,dc=com or the like.

$group_attr_val should be member, memberOf, or maybe Member, depending on whatever the member attribute is in your target LDAP directory.

So I think your issue is that group-attr=present is probably wrong and should be as simple as member instead.